# I can't figure out how to keep my buttons in HTML from moving when the page isnt full screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface

My webpage
[image: My webpage]
My webpage minimized
[image: My webpage minimized]

As you can see in the pictures, when it's full page it looks fine. but when I minimize the screen the buttons look off. How do i fix it? I want to keep my buttons from flying off here's my entire code.

I tried using the meta viewport tag but it didn't work.

```css
body {
  background-color: #F0EAD6;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #00704A;
  color: white;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.logo {
  width: 106px;
  height: 64px;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  color: #00704A;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: background-color 0.19s ease, color 0.19s ease;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #00704A;
  color: white;
}

#headright {
  margin-right: 55%;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<header class="header">
  <img class="logo" src="..\WP project\Central-Perk-Emblem.png" alt="Central Perk logo">
  <div id="headright">
    <a class="button" href="#">HOME</a>
    <a class="button" href="#">MENU</a>
    <a class="button" href="#">GIFT SHOP</a>
  </div>
  <div id="headleft">
    <a class="button" href="#">Find a Store</a>
    <a class="button" href="#">Sign In</a>
    <a class="button" href="#">Join Now</a>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nice design. So I think that your issue is probably in the fact that you are using percentages in the code. It's not the best practice to use percentage values in the margin. I think that's why the design keeps messing up. If you want to adjust the code to work for smaller screens you can always use media queries but never percentages. I made some adjustments to the code and also added a media query for smaller screens. You can check the code with the comments added. I'm using flex, specifically flex-end to push the buttons all the way to the end of the page(all the way to the right). I hope that helps.

```css
body {
  background-color: #F0EAD6;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #00704A;
  color: white;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.logo {
  width: 106px;
  height: 64px;
  margin-right: 10px; /* Updated: add some spacing to the right */
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  color: #00704A;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: background-color 0.19s ease, color 0.19s ease;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #00704A;
  color: white;
}

#headright {
  display: flex; /* Updated: enable flexbox layout */
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end; /* Updated: push buttons to the right end */
  flex-grow: 1; /* Updated: expand to take up remaining space */
}

#headleft {
  display: flex; /* Updated: enable flexbox layout */
  align-items: center;
}

#headleft .button {
  margin-right: 10px; /* Updated: add some spacing between buttons */
}

/* Added: media query to adjust layout for smaller screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .logo {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  #headright {
    justify-content: flex-start;
  }
  #headleft {
    margin-right: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <img class="logo" src="..\WP project\Central-Perk-Emblem.png" alt="Central Perk logo">
  <div id="headleft">
    <a class="button" href="#">HOME</a>
    <a class="button" href="#">MENU</a>
    <a class="button" href="#">GIFT SHOP</a>
  </div>
  <div id="headright">
    <a class="button" href="#">Find a Store</a>
    <a class="button" href="#">Sign In</a>
    <a class="button" href="#">Join Now</a>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes with margins, widths, paddings, heights.

I think the problem was happening due to lack of space.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: #F0EAD6;
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    .header {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-around;
      align-items: center;
      background-color: #00704A;
      color: white;
      height: 100px;
      padding: 0px 20px;
    }
    
    .logo {
      background: yellow;
      width: 106px;
      height: 64px;
      margin-right: 10px;
    }
    
    .button {
      min-width: 100px;
      display: inline-flex;
      padding: 5px 5px;
      border-radius: 20px;
      margin: 1px;
      background-color: white;
      color: #00704A;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-decoration: none;
      transition: background-color 0.19s ease, color 0.19s ease;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    
    .button:hover {
      background-color: #00704A;
      color: white;
    }
    /*#headright {
    margin-right: 55%; 
}*/
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <header class="header">
    <img class="logo" src="..\WP project\Central-Perk-Emblem.png" alt="Central Perk logo">
    <div id="headright">
      <a class="button" href="#">HOME</a>
      <a class="button" href="#">MENU</a>
      <a class="button" href="#">GIFT SHOP</a>
    </div>
    <div id="headleft">
      <a class="button" href="#">Find a Store</a>
      <a class="button" href="#">Sign In</a>
      <a class="button" href="#">Join Now</a>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give below to your *headright* and *headleft* because your container probably has some other `display` property due to which you cannot fit your buttons into that

```
display : flex;
flex-direction : row;
```

This should work.